# scanf by passing char

Tags: c, scanf

Eg I have following c code:

```
printf("please input : \r\n" ) ;


char ogn, subs;

scanf("%s %s",  &ogn, &subs);

printf("the two values are: %s %s", &ogn, &subs);
```

when running the code, eg i input "abc def" and exam ogn,subs,

I just get ogn = "ef"  and  subs = "def";

Can someone please explain it for me ?  I know in a 'string' case a 'char array' should be provided but here I just want to know why the 'char' variable accepting user input causes such result ?

Comment: A `char *` pointer can point to any number of chars - you have too few of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Th result is actually undefined behaviour.

Your program packs your memory like so:

subs | ogn | m | m | m | ...

where m is just random memory that your program allocates (Don't ask me why it's there if it wasn't there it would've segfaulted.)

now scanf loads "abc" into ogn so the memory looks like this

subs | 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | '\0' | ...

now scanf loads "def" into subs :

'd' | 'e' | 'f' | '\0' | '\0' | ..

now you tell it to print a string from ogn. thus up until the first terminating '\0':

"def"

now you tell it to print a string from sub up until '\0':

"ef"

And that is why you get the results that you are doing, but on a different compiler you might get a different result.

Don't do anything like that in any real program.

Answer (score 2):

Passing a pointer to a single `char` to `scanf` in a position corresponding to `%s` is always an undefined behavior, because `%s` writes at least two characters for a string (at least one character for string's body, and a null terminator).

Moreover, passing a pointer to a single `char` to `printf` in the position that corresponds to `%s` is undefined behavior, unless that char is set to `'\0'` (which isn't the case in your program).

Therefore, whatever printout you have is heavily compiler-dependent. The same program can crash on another computer, or produce an entirely different output.

In case of your particular compiler it appears that `ogn` is located in memory one character after `subs`, so it prints the content of `subs` starting with the second character.

To fix this, allocate arrays of at least four characters to your string variables (enough to fit three-character variables) and use the size specifier to limit the input:

```
char ogn[4], subs[4]; // enough for abs def; expand if you need more chars
scanf("%3s %3s", ogn, subs);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that passing a single `char` to the `printf()` function in the position that corresponds to `%s` is undefined behavior even in the case where that char has the value of `'\0'`. The reason for this is that you're passing an integer in a position where a variadic function is expecting a pointer, and for variadic functions passing the wrong type of variable is pretty much always undefined. (Also, don't forget, `int` and `char *` may not be the same size.)

Comment: @ElchononEdelson I wasn't talking about passing a single character, and that's not what the OP does either. I was talking about passing a pointer to a single character, which should be OK if that character happens to be `'\0'`.

Comment: Hmm. I misread what you wrote, and was therefore wrong. What you wrote seems to be correct.